# Why fuse blows in this circuit?

Tags: ac, converter, fuses

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdhnHp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hi, 
I am trying to build a 5VDC from my 220VAC (Switched-mode power supply). The first step is to convert AC-DC. Above is my schematic

- V1 is 220VAC, the peak is about 300V.
- C1 and C2 are the same, each has 200V voltage max rating.
- Thermistor is MF72-5D9 Surge Current Limiting.

When I turn on the power, F1 blows immediately. I do not know why. I check them out, no shortcut. Can someone help and tell me why?
Thank you very much!

EDIT: I found the rating of F1, it's 5A 250V.

Comment: You are storing E=0.5CV^2 very fast into some rather large capacitors, current limited by a 5 ohm resistor. What do you think the surge current will be? Is the fuse rated for it?

Comment: Friendly advice: If you're new to electronics, you shouldn't mess with mains voltage. Stick to low voltage projects until you're no longer new to electronics.

Comment: I don't think that circuit is going to produce 5Vdc anywhere. 300Vdc or 150Vdc, yes, 5Vdc, no. If you expect 5V at the right hand side and think it's safe to touch, you're going to get a dangerous shock.

Comment: I am going to use a transformer to step down the 300VDC, but my fuse blows before I can attach the transformer.

Comment: Thank you @Dampmaskin, no pain no gain though, but I am really careful ^^

Comment: You guy may realize it's the schematic of ATX power supply for +5VSB (first part of it though)

Comment: Being careful involves assessing risk, and not least knowing when you're not qualified to assess risk. But if you want to risk the life of yourself and potentially others, knock yourself out.

Comment: All the parts are from my old ATX power supply (a cheap one though), circuit too. And it worked, I just want to rebuild it and learn.

Comment: If you're going to attach a transformer to the DC side, you're going to be disappointed with the results.

Comment: Not only the transformer, there will be also IC to control the high-frequency switch, but it's not what I need here so I did not mention it, I just want to know why the fuse blows.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Morton, I am trying Switched-mode power supply, I was successful with 220 VAC to 9 VAC (or 12 VAC) already.

Comment: I am trying Switched-mode power supply, and if you can see, first step is to convert AC directly to DC. Anyway can someone please tell me why the fuse blows?

Comment: @Kalaradin I think you need to edit your question to add more details.

Comment: What’s the anp surge to the coil? Does it exceed the fuse’s rating?

Answer (score 2):

Use a different fuse, you most likely used a fast blowing fuse which trips as soon as an overcurrent occurs.

Instead use a slow blowing fuse which will trip slower and allows the inrush current that charges the capacitors to pass through without tripping.

Comment: Thank you, all the parts are from my old ATX power supply (a cheap one though), circuit too. And it worked before, this kind of fuse should stand the condition I think.

Comment: @Kalaradin the one key thing you haven't told us yet is what the fuse rating is.  Your circuit will take a big power surge when turned on - maybe as much as 60A for a very short time in the worst case.

Comment: I found the rating, it's 5A 250V. Should I connect the AC to inductors to limit the inrush current?

Comment: @Kalaradin An NTC thermistor is the usual method.

Comment: I already use it. Or it's not the one?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided enough detail for me to say why your fuse blows, but i can tell you how to figure out why your fuse blows.

1) Simulate this circuit,  either in circuitlab or Ltspice (probably preferred). From this,  you will know how much current you expect through the fuse during the turn on transient, and for how long.

2) Look up the data sheet for your fuse.  It will list curves showing current vs opening time.  If your initial inrush current lasts for longer than the fuse opening time for that current,  you have your answer.

If the inrush current spike is marginal, make sure you check the derating curves for your fuse.  Fuse trip point vary a lot over temperature and even from device to device, so make sure you've followed all the fuse derating guidelines in the datasheet.

If the fuse rating is clearly large enough,  you will need to post more information to figure out what's going on.